# Angularjs spring mvc html or jsp

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS.  I am trying to create simple project using AngulrJS with Spring concept. I want to know here difference bt JSP file  and HTML file, Where I am going to create HTML file and JSP file. I am just confused about this. 
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple project you can create any of them.

Html may be better cause you wont need any servlet container to run your angular app and you dont need any java for this - you can just open file-system file in browser.

Jsp gives you additional possibilities thow.

Comment: Thank you.  Let me go with html.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why they down voted you, it is kind of confusing at first, Im running with html only, but you can use jsp or thymeleafs too if you like to do a mix with server side stuff, i dont really recomend this it gets kind of messy and you are kind of forced to provide a controller for partials.

To start off you have to put the index.html in the src/main/resources/static 
then if you have not set a controller for "/" it will serve index.html

Good luck.